# How to find Commit Charge programmatically?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the total [commit charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_charge).

Comment: Commit charge as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_charge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public static long GetCommitCharge()
    {
        var p = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Committed Bytes");
        return p.RawValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using WMI:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objSWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer)
Set colSWbemObjectSet = _
 objSWbemServices.InstancesOf("Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration")

For Each objSWbemObject In colSWbemObjectSet
 Wscript.Echo "Total Physical Memory (kb): " & _
 objSWbemObject.TotalPhysicalMemory
 WScript.Echo "Total Virtual Memory (kb): " & _
 objSWbemObject.TotalVirtualMemory
 WScript.Echo "Total Page File Space (kb): " & _
 objSWbemObject.TotalPageFileSpace
Next
```

If you run this script under CScript, you should see the number of kilobytes of physical memory installed on the target computer displayed in the command window. The following is typical output from the script:
Total Physical Memory (kb): 261676

**Edit:** Included total page file size property also

taken from: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_wmi_dieu.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I don't think this shows the value of Commit Charge.  This shows total physical/virtual memory installed, right?

Comment: edited to include total page file size also - sorry bout that